# How to get tzinfo from ActiveSupport::TimeZones.zones_map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, validating

I'm trying to retrieve an array of all time zones tzinfo but I only need the "America/Los_Angeles" part from each so I can validate timezones being received from an iOS mobile client. Currently running the following:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.collect { |z| z.tzinfo }
```

I get the class `TZInfo::TimezoneProxy` along with the info I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.values
```

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late response.... BUT I ended up going with time_zones = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.collect { |z| z.tzinfo.identifier }.

Comment: Your answer is way cleaner

Answer (score 1):

The zones in [ActiveSupport::Timezones](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) are limited to a subset of 146 "meaningful" zones, though they do not define by what critera they determine which zones are "meaningful".

If you use it to validate IANA time zone identifiers coming from another platform, you will certainly have false negatives, as there are over 500 of them.

Instead, use the [TZinfo Gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/) directly, rather than Rail's strange mutated version of it.  See also the section on Rails Time Zone Identifiers in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: The Norwegian capital Oslo is not in the "meaningful" list, but Srednekolymsk (pop. 3525) is.  Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Found the instance method "identifier" in the documentation - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/TimezoneProxy#_load-class_method

So all I needed was

ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.collect{|z| z.tzinfo.identifier }